# Initialize react-native application with class components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, create-react-native-app

I have just installed `create-react-native-app` and created one. I can see that `app` is a function there

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.tsx to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I know that both Functional and  Class-Components in available in React. Now I want to create app with Class Components. Can somebody suggest how to do it?

Comment: There are plenty of quality resources on the internet on how to use class based components. Is there any specific point that you do not understand? If not you may study the docs first.

Comment: I am sorry to be not clear. I am just interested what is the command that creates skeleton of Class component. I tried `create-react-native-app` that creates Functional one.

Comment: What is the difficulty in taking a random react tutorial and writing the few lines it needs yourself in an editor for your choice? I can't see how you need a command for that. When developing even a small react application you will need to write all of the components yourself anyways including class based components which you will certainly need at some point. There is no command for that. The only reason `create-react-native-app` does this is to help you figure out if your setup is working without having to first create a component. Usually you will delete that one as the next step.

Comment: I assumed that here should be something similar to `ng generate component` from Angular. Now it is clear, there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

For people who come from heavy object-oriented background, the class-based component will let them jump on `reactjs` relatively quickly compared to a functional-based component.

Here is some basic skeleton of the class component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    // Where you initialize some data
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    // Lifecycle method when your component is mounted
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Lifecycle method when your component is unmounted
  }

  _handleOnButtonPress = () => {
    // Handler when your button is pressed
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handleOnButtonPress}>
          <Text>Open up App.tsx to start working on your app!</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is a further [reference](https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108) to compare class and functional component. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for you :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text, 
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    // initial method
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Test</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make it a class unless you are using state in the class